# Size of $\epsilon$-net on a $2$-dimensional compact manifold

Tags: general-topology, riemannian-geometry, dimension-theory-analysis

I'm dealing with a $2$ dimensional compact Riemannian manifold on which I consider the distance induced by the metric. I would like to know the behavior of the size of an $\epsilon$-net when $\epsilon \to 0^+$.

If $M$ is my manifold i say that $X \subset M$ is an $\epsilon$-net if for every $x \in M$ there exists a $z \in X$ s.t. $d(x,z) < \epsilon$. Define 
$$ N(\epsilon) = \inf \{ |X| \mid X \text{ is a } \epsilon - \text{ net } \} < + \infty $$

I'm wondering if I can say something like
$$ N(\epsilon) \le C\epsilon^{-2}$$

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question (I am fairly sure that it is "Yes," but I don't know enough about Riemannian geometry to be certain), however it could be rephrased as "Is the box-counting dimension of a compact two-dimensional Riemannian manifold bounded by $2$?"  This might give you something to Google.  I've added the [tag:dimension-theory] tag to your question---this might get some attention from someone more knowledgable than myself.

Answer (score 1):

This is false, because if $X$ is an $\epsilon$ net by your definition then any subset of $M$ containing $X$ is also an $\epsilon$ net. So, for example, the entire surface $X=M$ satisfies your definition of an $\epsilon$ net, and that is an uncountably infinite set.

I suspect that your definition of an $\epsilon$ net is missing some important clauses.

Comment: You are right, I edited my question!